# Есть два репозитория, и три связанные таблицы. Как правильно описать созданние объектов с помощью JDBC

Tags: java, sql, шаблоны-проектирования, jdbc, repository

У меня есть такая база данных проекта.

В ней есть таблицы: (Profile и Menu) и (Menu и Products) со связью Many-to-Many. То есть у профиля есть много меню, и одно меню есть у многих профилей, и так же для продуктов.

В своем слое обрабатывающем данные я использую паттерн Repository. Например, для первого варианта: ProfileRepository и MenuRepository. Проблема в том, что я не знаю, где правильно разместить SQL запросы для третьей связывающей их таблицы. Сейчас у меня выходит "макаронный" код.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть, для создания объекта профиль у меня идет вызов -> ProfileRepository.read(Id) -> внутри него идет SQL запрос сперва что бы получить профиль, потом что бы получить из связывающей таблицы все id меню, затем вызов MenuRepository и передача этих id.

У меня получается каша из вызовов репозитория внутри репозитория. Я сейчас, думаю сделать это с помощью транзакций, либо сделать слой ДАО под слоем репозиториев, где будут описанные ВСЕ таблицы, и вызывать из репозитория нужные дао для сборки объекта. Сумбурно выражаюсь, трудно разобраться во всех этих абстракциях.Спасибо за помощь.

Вот пример запроса на чтение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слишком мало информации о требованиях, чтобы однозначно какое-то решение рекомендовать. Напишу в общем, как пищу для размышления, а решать, что в вашем случае делать, все равно вам.

У проблемы есть несколько уровней. Разберем поочередно.

### Нужно ли вообще подгружать ассоциации?

В первую очередь я бы хорошо взвесил за и против и подумал, действительно ли нужно подгружать ассоциации. То, что можно загрузить, например, профиль и потом использовать ассоциированные меню, конечно удобно. Но, во-первых, далеко не во всех случаях, когда вы загружаете профиль понадобятся связанные с ним меню (а платить за это придется временем загрузки, памятью и временем сборщика мусора).

Следующий, неочевидный момент. Представьте, что профиль связан з несколькими меню, а те в свою очередь с другими профилями, а те еще с очередными меню. Если загрузка объекта по идентификатору, автоматически подгружает ассоциации, то, во-первых, в зависимости от того, какая структура данных, невинный запрос достать один профиль может загрузить всю базу в память. Даже если этого не будет, прийдется при загрузке связанного с профилем меню, не загружать повторно сам профиль, иначе выйдет бесконечная рекурсия - профиль загружает меню, а меню профиль.

Вывод из этого такой, нужно контролировать, какую часть графа объектов мы подгружаем. Это обычно зависит от сценария использования. (Для отображения короткой информации о профиле меню вообще могут быть не нужны, для страницы детальной информации о профиле, могут понадобится непосредственно ассоциированные меню). Самый простой вариант, не пытаться создать универсальные методы, а начать з сценариев, и для сценария сделать метод, которые достает нужные данные. А потом уже смотреть, что можно унифицировать - но при этом не переборщить.

### Каша вызовов

Каша получается потому, что в таком виде как есть у метода `Profile read(Long id)` сразу несколько ответственностей. И поэтому трудно увидеть структуру кода и ее улучшить.

Что я имею ввиду? Во-первых, в методе смешаны сразу несколько уровней абстракции. С одной стороны метод делает запросы через JDBC, с другой - собирает ассоциированные объекты. Если вынести в отдельный метод вичитывание объекта, то это это поможет лучше увидеть внутренние закономерности и улучшить код (часто трудно увидеть такие закономерности и разделение кода по уровням помогает структурировать код и открывает дорогу к дальнейшим улучшениям, которые неочевидны поначалу):

```
Profile read(Long id) {
   Profile profile = readWithoutAssociations(id);
   Set<Menu> menus = readMenusByProfileId(id);
   profile.setMenus(menus);
}

Profile readWithoutAssociations(Long id) {

   try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(..)) {
      Profile profile = new Profile();
      ... считывание з помощью jdbc API всех полей из таблицы profiles
   }
   return profile;
}

Set<Menu> readMenusByProfileId(Long id) {
    ... тут запрос к таблице ассоциаций и таблице menu
}
```

После такого изменения, становится уже "виднее", что метод `readMenusByProfileId` логичнее всего перенести в `menuRepository` (т.к. он возвращает объекты меню). Для репозитория не так важно откуда читает (в смысле из каких таблиц) - гораздо важнее, какие объекты возвращает. Репозиторий вообще может быть в памяти, и тут вообще понятие таблиц неприменимо.

В вашем случае сущности, которые представляют собой ассоциации вообще не представлены в коде, есть только классы для концов ассоциаций. По-этому, достаточно двух репозиториев - один возвращает меню, второй - профили.

Далее, нет смысла читать таблицу `profile_menus` и потом читать записи из `menu` по одной. Гораздо лучше, сделать один запрос чтобы получить все меню ассоциированные с профилем:

```
select m.* from menu m
   join profile_menu pm on pm.menu_id = m.id
where pm.profile_id = PROFILE_ID
```

Это и упростит код и сделает его гораздо быстрее, так как вместо 1+n будет выполнятся 1 запрос, который достанет сразу всю коллекцию.

### Вывод

В конечном итоге все может выглядеть как-то так:

```
class ProfileRepository {
 public Profile read(Long id) {
 }
 public Profile readWithoutAssociations(Long id) {
 }
 public Set<Profile> readByMenuId(Long menuId) {
    ... использует profile_menus чтобы по menu_id найти все связанные профили
 }
}
```

Аналогично и `MenuRepository`.

Конечно, как я писал выше, все зависит, от сценариев т.е. того, какие данные нужно читать в разных случаях.

Comment: Спасибо за подробное объяснение, очень доходчиво. Посоветуете материалы, где разбирают похожие вопросы? Я столкнулся с тем, что эта тема везде подается довольно абстрактно, и скомкано. Хотелось бы изучить глубже.

Comment: Трудно посоветовать что-то, что прям вот в тему. Часто, действительно, это довольно абстрактные вещи. Чтобы абстрактные советы помогли, нужны какие-то зацепки, которые появляются с опытом. Идеальный вариант - это design и code review з опытным коллегой. А в общем из книг могу порекомендовать Clean Code и, особенно, Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests.